# Binding Size of an Element to another in WPF (.xaml) and adding variable length to the bound size

Tags: wpf, xaml

Suppose I want to bind the Width and Height of an element to another element, for example as shown below:

`<Image x:Name="image" .... />`

`<Grid x:Name="gridOverlay" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=image}" Height="{BindingActualWidth, ElementName=image}" />`

Is it possible to set the width and height of the grid to be a bit larger than that of the image?
i.e. the dimensions of the grid to be:

Width = (Width of image) + x
Height = (Width of image) + y

Comment: Use an appropriate Binding Converter. Note however that binding an element's size to that of another element is usually pointless, because most of the time it can be done by choosing appropriate layout panels.

Answer (score 0):

Try nest 2 Grids and set Margin property as you need.

```
<Grid> 
    <Image /> 
    <Grid Margin="x,y" />
</Grid>
```

where *x* and *y* are the margins you wanna get.